# Как вычислить все возможные комбинации элементов в массиве?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, разработка-игр, комбинаторика

Пишу игру на js. Есть массив из 5 элементов^
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

Мне нужно получить все возможные сочетания элементов этого массива при том, что элементов может быть от 1 до 5. Т.е.:
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; ['b', 'e']; ['a', 'c', 'd']; ['d'] итд...

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 8):

То, что вы хотите, называется не сочетаниями, а кортежами.
Простейший способ - цикл от 0 до 31 (2^5-1), и в каждом кортеже имеются те элементы, которые соответствуют единичным битам числа.

Другие варианты генерации всех кортежей вы можете найти в книге Д. Кнута *Искусство программирования, т.4А*.

Answer (score 5):

JS не очень хорошо знаю, но попробую предложить решение.

1. В цикле перебираете числа от 1 до 31.
2. Для каждого значения переводите в двоичную форму. Например так:

   i.toString(2)

   Получаете строку примерно такого вида: 11010
3. Выбираете те элементы массива, для которых на соответствующей позиции стоит 1, и игнорируете те, для которых ноль. Например с помощью функции filter:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']  

  for(i=1; i<=31; i++) {
   b = i.toString(2)
   while(b.length < 5) {b = '0' + b}
   
   var farr = arr.filter( function(item, n, arr) { return b.charAt(4-n) > 0 })
   document.writeln(farr + '<br>')
    }
```